# Validaciones dentro del SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Actualmente tengo el siguiente flujo en un SSIS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es, hay alguna forma de colocar un OLE DB, que me permita insertar información a una tabla llamada errores si el Excel Source llega a fallar, en pocas palabras, si el archivo de Excel no existe, quiero guardar 3 cosas en la tabla de errores, las cuales serían, la fecha, una acción y el mensaje que produce. ¿Es posible realizar esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma en la que se suele manejar esto en **SSIS** es la siguiente:

1. Ir a la pestaña de 'Controladores de eventos' del paquete.
2. Seleccionar el ejecutable correspondiente. En este caso tu 'Tarea de flujo de datos'.
3. Seleccionar el evento que quieres capturar, en este caso un error (OnError).
4. Añadir el elemento o conjunto de elementos que deben ejecutarse cuando se produzca el error.

En la siguiente imagen puedes ver resumido el proceso:

[image: Controlar eventos en SSIS]

Para tu caso (Realizar una inserción cuando se produzca un error), lo que se puede hacer es añadir un elemento 'Ejecutar SQL', con una conexión a tu **OLE DB** a tu base de datos. Dentro del campo **SQLStatement** añadimos la consulta SQL que queramos, como se puede ver en el siguiente ejemplo:

[image: Ejecutar SQL tras un evento]

Y por último, en la sección de la izquierda 'Asignación de parámetros', asignamos los datos que queremos insertar en nuestra tabla. En el siguiente ejemplo estamos guardando la fecha de inicio de ejecución del paquete y la descripción del error que se ha producido:

[image: Asignación de parámetros SQL]

Puedes encontrar todas las variables de sistema que se pueden usar en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/integration-services/system-variables?view=sql-server-2017). También puedes usar variables propias que hayas definido previamente en el paquete.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda Dan Novek, pero no sé que estaré haciendo mal, me lanza la pantalla de error (Package Validation Error), pero no guarda el error, lo que hago es cambiar el nombre del archivo del excel y no hace nada el ETL, el Event Handler no es activado.

Comment: Olvida lo que dije antes, ya pude, la propiedad ValidateExternalMetadata estaba en true, la cambié a false y el Event Handler se activó correctamente, gracias por la ayuda...